# InDesign XML-import: How to use style groups?

Tags: xml, import, adobe-indesign

The task is to import an XML file into InDesign which looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/">
   <p aid:pstyle="Style1">Testtext</p>
</doc>
```

Now, I'd prefer not to address the simple paragraph style `Style1` but instead one in a style group (or style folder) like `Style Group/Style1`

[image]

I tried `@aid:pstyle="Style Group/Style1"` as well as `@aid:pstyle="Style Group:Style1"` as well as `@aid:pstyle="Style Group%3aStyle1"`. No luck.

Any idea how to address style groups while importing XML data into InDesign?

Comment: It looks like there is still no way to do it: https://indesign.uservoice.com/forums/601021-adobe-indesign-feature-requests/suggestions/32562304-style-group-support-via-xml-import